# How to solve 'IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a condition for methods that return a value' in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, illegalargumentexception

I have a Spring Cloud Stream application handling Dead letter queue.

Here I handle the record forwarded to the DLQ topic like below -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class EventDrivenApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EventDrivenApplication.class, args);
}

@StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT)
@SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
public Message<?> reRoute(Message<?> failed) {
Integer retries = failed.getHeaders().get("x-retries", Integer.class);

if (retries == null) {
        log.info("First retry for {}", failed);
        return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(failed)
                .setHeader(X_RETRIES_HEADER, new Integer(1))
                .setHeader(BinderHeaders.PARTITION_OVERRIDE, failed.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID))
                .build();
    } else if (retries.intValue() < 3) {
        log.info("Another retry for {}", failed);
        return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(failed)
                .setHeader(X_RETRIES_HEADER, new Integer(retries.intValue() + 1))
                .setHeader(BinderHeaders.PARTITION_OVERRIDE, failed.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID))
                .build();
    }
return null;
}
}
```

When I run this application, I get below error -

```
SpringApplication : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a condition for methods that return a value
```

Why can't we write conditional statements in a method that has return value ?

I would really appreciate if someone helps me solve this.

Comment: @gary-russell sir can you please help ..

Answer (score 1):

`conditions` are not supported on request/reply methods.

When using conditions, multiple listeners can get the same message and they both cannot return a reply.

I suppose the check could have been more lenient, but it's not.